# 'or' within a constraint :docplex

Tags: python, cplex, docplex

Using OPL I could do the write below constraint.Mainly I used or(||) within a constraint and successfully get the results.na_supply_component is 2d decision variable

```
// MOQ (Minimum Order Quantity) 
con2: forall(i in 1..12,j in 1..5)
na_supply_component[j,i]>=na_moq_supplier[j] || na_supply_component[j,i]==0;
```

Now I am trying to convert my OPL code into python using docplex package.
Sample code as follows.Here I have used 1d Decision variable just to check(purch_val)

```
Supplier=['q','w','e','r','t'];
n_Supplier=len(Supplier);
r_Supplier=range(n_Supplier);
na_moq_supplier=[10,20,30,40,0]
from docplex.mp.model import Model

x=Model("mymod");
purch_val=x.integer_var_list(n_Supplier,lb=0,ub=10000);
for i in r_Supplier:x.add_constraint(purch_val[i]>=na_moq_supplier[i] or purch_val[i]==0);
```

When I run I get an error `TypeError: Cannot convert a linear constraint to boolean: x1 >= 10`
It does not allow me to use `or`.Could you exaplain what can I do to overcome this error.

Answer (score 0):

```
from docplex.mp.model import Model

mdl = Model(name='buses')
nbbus40 = mdl.integer_var(name='nbBus40')
nbbus30 = mdl.integer_var(name='nbBus30')
mdl.add_constraint(nbbus40*40 + nbbus30*30 >= 300, 'kids')
mdl.minimize(nbbus40*460 + nbbus30*360)

mdl.solve()

for v in mdl.iter_integer_vars():
    print(v," = ",v.solution_value)

print()
print("with the logical constraint")

mdl.add((nbbus40>=7) + (nbbus30>=7)>=1)



mdl.solve()

for v in mdl.iter_integer_vars():
    print(v," = ",v.solution_value)
```

works fine

and gives

```
nbBus40  =  6.0
nbBus30  =  2.0

with the logical constraint
nbBus40  =  7.0
nbBus30  =  1.0
```

from [logical constraints](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/making-optimization-simple-python-alex-fleischer/)